# Prestodb (AWS EMR) load partition metadata

Tags: amazon-emr, presto

I have AWS EMR cluster with Prestodb v. 0.238.3
Everything is fine except one thing - when I call a function to collect data of partitions it always fails. I tried to execute this command via Datagrip (+ jdbc driver) and via presto-cli on master node of the cluster - no difference

```
CALL system.metadata.sync_partition_metadata('test', 'table_test', 'FULL')

[29] Query failed (#20201124_193910_00688_37bpw): 
Procedure not registered: system.sync_partition_metadata com.facebook.presto.spi.PrestoException: 
Procedure not registered: system.sync_partition_metadata
```

What do I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

That function is available starting with Presto 304: https://trino.io/docs/current/release/release-304.html?highlight=sync_partition_metadata#hive-connector-changes

The documentation is available here: https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html?highlight=sync_partition_metadata#procedures

In EMR, it's available with EMR version 6.1.0, which includes Presto 338:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-6x.html

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems I was confused by Presto & PrestoSQL. EMR 6.1 has Presto 0.232 while EMR 5.31 (I am using) has Presto 0.238.3. I found doc link you provided and saw release date for that procedure - 19 feb 2019.

Answer (score 1):

This function is available starting with version 0.241 in PrestoDB.

You can either bootstrap your EMR with a later version of PrestoDB, or use a managed service like https://ahana.io/ahana-cloud/

Doc: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#procedures